# Inverse trig function integration by parts.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

1. $$\int \tan^{-1}{2y}dy$$

if I choose $u = \tan^{-1}{2y}$ then $du = \frac{2}{1 + (2y)^2} dy$

and

$dv = dy$ and $v = y$

But I have a more complicated du. What else can I do?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768332/liate-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 1):

Another approach. Let $2y = \tan(\theta) \rightarrow 2\frac{dy}{d\theta} = \sec^2(\theta)$ and finally $dy = \frac{1}{2}\sec^2(\theta)d\theta$.

Thus,

\begin{align}
I =\int \arctan(2y)\:dy = \int \arctan\left(\tan(\theta)\right) \cdot \frac{1}{2}\sec^2(\theta)\:d\theta = \frac{1}{2}\int \theta \sec^2(\theta)\:d\theta
\end{align}

Now, integrate by parts:

\begin{align}
    v'(\theta) &= \sec^2(\theta) & u(\theta) &= \theta \\
    v(\theta) &= \tan(\theta) & u'(\theta) &= 1
\end{align}

Thus:

\begin{align}
I &= \frac{1}{2}\int \theta \sec^2(\theta)\:d\theta = \frac{1}{2}\left[\theta\tan(\theta) - \int \tan(\theta) \:d\theta \right]  \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\theta\tan(\theta) - \ln\left|\sec(\theta) \right| \right] + C
\end{align}

Where $C$ is the constant of integration. Recall that $2y = \tan(\theta)$ and hence $\theta = \arctan(2y)$. For $\sec(\theta)$ we use the identity $\sec(\theta) = \sqrt{\tan^2(\theta)+ 1} = \sqrt{\left(2y\right)^2 + 1} = \sqrt{4y^2 + 1}$. Hence we arrive at

\begin{equation}
I = \int \arctan(2y)\:dy = \frac{1}{2}\left[2y \arctan(2y) - \ln\left| \sqrt{4y^2 + 1} \right|\right] + C = y \arctan(2y) - \frac{1}{4}\ln\left| 4y^2 + 1 \right| + C
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

A neat identity.

Given some continuous inverse function $f^{-1}(x)$, we can find the antiderivative of this inverse function. Here's how.

Consider the integral
$$I=\int f^{-1}(x)\mathrm dx$$
Assuming that we know what $f(x)$ is, we may preform the substitution $x=f(t)$ meaning that $\mathrm dx=f'(t)\mathrm dt$. Hence we have
$$I=\int f^{-1}\left[f(t)\right]f'(t)\mathrm dt$$
$$I=\int tf'(t)\mathrm dt$$
We then integrate by parts: 
$$\mathrm dv=f'(t)\mathrm dt\Rightarrow v=f(t)\\
u=t\Rightarrow \mathrm du=\mathrm dt$$
Which gives
$$I=tf(t)-\int f(t)\mathrm dt$$
And assuming that $F'(x)=f(x)$,
$$I=tf(t)-F(t)+C$$
And since $x=f(t)$ we have that $t=f^{-1}(x)$ which gives
$$I=xf^{-1}(x)-F\left[f^{-1}(x)\right]+C$$

---

So, choosing $f^{-1}(x)=\arctan ax$ for some constant $a\neq 0$, we have that $f(x)=\frac1a\tan x$. Hence 
$$\begin{align}
I&=x\arctan ax-\frac1a\int \tan t \,\mathrm dt\\
&=x\arctan ax+\frac1a\ln\left|\cos t\right|+C\\
&=x\arctan ax+\frac1a\ln\left|\cos[\arctan ax]\right|+C
\end{align}$$
And from $$\cos[\arctan z]=\frac1{\sqrt{1+z^2}}$$
We have, after some simplification, 
$$\int\arctan(ax)\mathrm dx=x\arctan(ax)-\frac1{2a}\ln(1+a^2x^2)+C$$
And your integral is given by the case $a=2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\arctan2ydy=y\arctan2y-\int\frac{2y}{1+4y^2}dy=y\arctan2y-\frac{1}{4}\ln(1+4y^2)+C.$$

Answer (score 0):

Integrating by parts, $\int tan^{-1}(2y)\, dy=y\, tan^{-1}(2y) -\int \frac {2y} {1+4y^{2}} \, dy+c$. Put $1+4y^{2}=u$ to evaluate this.